# Possible way to get objects from Parse.com in intervals of 5 on .NET MVC?

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, parse-platform

My current system loads all items at once, and displays them 5 at a time using a variation of [MVC Infinite Scroll](http://www.devtxt.com/blog/asp-net-mvc-infinite-scrolling). However, as the database gets larger the initial loading times are sluggish.

Does Parse.com allow querying items by using an index?
What could be a potential fix or angle to solve problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, the `ParseQuery` class has a method to skip (query.Skip(n)) an amount of objects and also to limit (query.Limit(n)) the amount of objects to be returned by a query.

Basically you keep track of the current limit and then just increase the values for skip and limit by the amount of items you want to load.

You can find details in the [API reference](http://www.parse.com/docs/dotnet/api/Index.html) of their .Net SDK.

Comment: Outstanding! How did I not think of it before. Thanks a bunch!